# vb.net why is model only showing one make of car yet my cars is showing full lest

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I have a problem with the combox its only displaying the first item in the list its being populated by a webserice call the drop down in question is comboboxmodel now the manufacture one is fine and sets as it should any reason as to why the comboboxmodel would not.

Please provide your answer in vb.net thanks

```
If dt Is Nothing Then
  ASPxTextBox1.ErrorText = "Invalid VRM"
  Exit Sub
End If

ComboBoxManufacturer.SelectedIndex = ComboBoxManufacturer.Items.IndexOfText(dt.Rows(0)("MamMake").ToString.Trim)
Page.Title = dt.Rows(0)("MamModel").ToString.Trim

ComboBoxModel.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0)("MamModel").ToString.Trim)
ComboBoxModel.SelectedIndex = ComboBoxModel.Items.IndexOfText(dt.Rows(0)("MamModel").ToString.Trim)
'    fillModel(ComboBoxManufacturer.Text) '

ComboBoxEngine.SelectedIndex = 0
ComboBoxSubModel.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0)("MamSModel").ToString.Trim)

ComboBoxEngine.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0)("MamEngSize").ToString.Trim)
ComboBoxEngine.SelectedIndex = 0

ComboBoxYear.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0)("YearOfManufacture").ToString.Trim)
ComboBoxYear.SelectedIndex = 0


' MsgBox(dt.Rows(0)("Fuel").ToString.Trim.ToLowerInvariant()) '

ComboBoxFuelType.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0)("Fuel").ToString.Trim.ToUpper())
ComboBoxFuelType.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question. I can't even find a question. Please restructure your explanation and question.

Comment: If you are looking for a vb.net solution then why did you include a C# tag?

Answer (score 1):

well your question is so ambiguous, so I assume you say whenever you open it, it's allways first item. If it is the issue,

ComboBoxYear.SelectedIndex = 0

that'll give you a lead. Whenever you add a new item into combobox, you also set selected index 0, so just remove it or select anyone you want.